# How to add animations in Java Swing class without flash?

Tags: java, swing, animation, transition

I am making a basic java application and I was just wondering how I can add animations to my swing class. I wanted to know about animations like:

- JPanel transitions (fade-in/out, dissolve, etc)
- JButton click animations
- JOptionPane transitions
- JLabel color animations

The animations just need to be basic. Things you could do in Powerpoint. Anyone know how this can be done?

Comment: Look into how `paintComponent` works and combine this with a `SwingWorker` to achieve a time-constrained custom effect. This probably won't mesh well with look and feel variations though. JavaFX probably handles this better without as many modifications.

Comment: Some examples using Swing `Timer` are seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a230513%20javax.swing.Timer%20paintComponent).

Comment: @trashgod So are you saying I have to use the timer to change the label image each second or something?

Comment: @LakshyaGoyal: Yes; I've elaborated below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swing doesn't have any good/sensible support for animations or transitions. You might want to have a look at JavaFX instead.

Answer (score 3):

While JavaFX has strong support for [animations and transitions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/visual-effects-tutorial/animations.htm#JFXTE149), a Swing [`Timer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) or [`SwingWorker`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) can be used to achieve many similar effects. A number of examples are shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3A230513%20Timer%20paintComponent) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3A230513%20paintComponent%20%20SwingWorker).